# Phoenix framework - execute NPM script in subdirectory

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix app, I am running a React frontend that sits in an `assets/` directory within the app... it has it's own `package.json` file, and I would like to be able to run aliased NPM scripts from the Phoenix app's `mix.exs` file. I've been experimenting with Elixir's `System.cmd()`, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Basically, I've set up a lint command for my frontend - in `assets/package.json`, I've got

```
"lint": "eslint ./*.js ./js/*.js || exit 0"
```

and running `$ npm run lint` from the `assets/` directory works as expected... but it would be smashing to just be able to run the command from the app's top-level.

In my `mix.exs` file, I was experimenting with an alias like so:

```
defp aliases do
  [
    "lint": [System.cmd("npm", ["run lint"], cd: "assets")
  ]
end
```

but running `mix lint` produces a pretty wordy error:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Mix.Task.run_alias/3    

The following arguments were given to Mix.Task.run_alias/3:

    # 1
    [{"\nUsage: npm <command>\n\nwhere <command> is one of:\n    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,\n    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, edit, explore, get,\n    help, help-search, i, init, install, install-test, it, link,\n    list, ln, login, logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping,\n    prefix, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,\n    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,\n    stars, start, stop, t, tag, team, test, tst, un, uninstall,\n    unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view, whoami\n\nnpm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>\nnpm -l           display full usage info\nnpm help <term>  search for help on <term>\nnpm help npm     involved overview\n\nSpecify configs in the ini-formatted file:\n    /Users/user/.npmrc\nor on the command line via: npm <command> --key value\nConfig info can be viewed via: npm help config\n\nnpm@3.10.10 /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm\n", 1}]

    # 2
    []

    # 3
    :ok

Attempted function clauses (showing 3 out of 3):

    defp run_alias([h | t], alias_args, _res) when is_binary(h)
    defp run_alias([h | t], alias_args, _res) when is_function(h, 1)
    defp run_alias([], _alias_task, res)

(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:331: Mix.Task.run_alias/3
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:266: Mix.Task.run/2
(mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:75: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
(elixir) lib/code.ex:376: Code.require_file/2
```

Ok so obviously I'm doing something wrong. Is it possible to execute an NPM command on a sub-directory of a Phoenix app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `run` and `lint` should be separate strings in the arguments list.

Secondly, the code you have will immediately run the command instead of when the alias is invoked.

You can use a `"run -e ..."` alias to execute arbitrary code in an alias like this:

```
"lint": [~s|run -e 'System.cmd("npm", ["run", "lint"], cd: "assets")'|)
```

(I'm using `~s||` syntax just to make it easier to type a string with both single and double quotes.)

Comment: Awesome! This seems to work correctly, but two quick things... 1. there's a small typo in your code - closing paren should be a bracket. When I fixed that, the app compiled and the task ran without error. However, 2. the output of the task was not visible in the terminal. Is there a way that I can pipe the output into the existing shell? I looked at the options in the `System` docs but didn't see anything. (I did try adding an `IO.inspect` before `System...` and that did return the output, though not with the tidy ESLint formatting...).

Comment: Ah, got it!  Just had to add `into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line)` to the options - `[cd: "assets", into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line)]`.  Thanks Dogbert!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is also an extension you can use to do this, but unfortunately it's unable to traverse paths. But maybe it will be patched.

https://github.com/verdammelt/mix_npm

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the ~s|| notation with a `cd`, we can also use the `--prefix` flag on the npm command.

```
lintjs: ["cmd npm run format:ci --prefix assets"]
```

If using an umbrella project, define the alias in the app where it runs, and add an alias in the project root.

`<root>/mix.exs`

```
defp aliases do
    [
      # run `mix setup` in all child apps
      setup: ["cmd mix setup"],
      # app-specific alias defined in onstage_web/mix.exs
      lint: ["cmd --app myapp_name mix lintjs"]
    ]
end
```

`<root>/apps/myapp_name/mix.exs`

```
defp aliases do
    [
      # run npm install in child app
      setup: ["deps.get", "cmd npm install --prefix assets"],,
      # simplified/equivalent of accepted answer
      lintjs: ["cmd npm run format:ci --prefix assets"]
    ]
end
```

Now, we can run `mix lint` from the project root to lint the JS in a child app.

Also, remember to run `mix compile` after making changes.